# What's a terraform block used for?

Tags: terraform

I see a file like this in my Terraform code:

```
terraform {
  required_version = ">= 0.12"
}
```

but I'm not clear what the outer `terraform {..}` block is for and can't find any documentation.

I've seen `output`, `resource`, `data`, etc but not `terraform`. Any suggestions (or documentation)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is basically for the top level configuration of your terraform environment. For example, the version lock you are using. And you can set the your "backend"/source of tfstate file and more.

With my experience, you would need this require_version and backend specified to guarantee your environment is clean and consistent.

Here is the doc for terraoform block: https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/terraform.html